# image always placed in top of dialog

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I am displaying image in the dialog box which contains the zoom view as well. Here image is placed and zoom is working fine without any issue but problem is image is always placed in the top of the dialog and if i scroll down it comes to middle then zoom happens. I dont want like this instead image should display in the middle and i need to do the zoom.

I am using dynamic imageview and for zoom using chrisbanes photoview library. If i remove the library the image is placed in the center.

```
 @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Dialog builder = new Dialog(listdisplay, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
                builder.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                builder.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                        new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK));
                builder.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                        //nothing;
                    }
                });

 ImageView imageView = new ImageView(listdisplay);
                      Glide.with(finalConvertView.getContext()).load(Limage).fitCenter()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).into(imageView);

                DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                listdisplay.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);


                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp =  new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(metrics.widthPixels,
                        metrics.heightPixels);

                imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);

                //imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
                 p = new PhotoViewAttacher(imageView);


                builder.addContentView(imageView, lp);
                builder.show();
            }
        });
```

i tried with scaletype for imageview as center but image is placed in top of the dialog.

[image]

[image]

Comment: why didt you create your own dialog layout?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question?

Answer (score 0):

**Use Custom dialog for you own dialog design**

```
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
            dialog.setTitle("Title...");

            // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
            TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setText("Android custom dialog example!");
            ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
            // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            dialog.show();
```

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFF" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"/>/>

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialogButtonOK"
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" Ok "
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```